# Operators.NotObject VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have an operator declared like this as I am translating code from VB to C#
But `Operators.NotObject(...)` is not part of C#. Could you tell what this operator does in VB and if there is equivalent thing in C#?

```
public static object operator !=(TopologyEdge A, TopologyEdge B)
{
    return Operators.NotObject(A == B);
}
```

Comment: Looks like `Object.Equals`

Comment: That operator only has one argument.  It is only ever used in dynamically typed code.  That is pretty common in VB.NET, lots of programmers like Option Strict Off.  But not in C#, quite unlikely that you'll need it once the conversion is done.  You'd have to use the `dynamic` keyword if you want to limp along.  Or just keep using Operators.NotObject(), its implementation is pretty untrivial and it works fine in C# as well.

Comment: To expand on what Hans said, you would need to add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly and the fully qualified call is Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.NotObject (you would need a 'using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices' statement to keep the call as a simple 'Operators.NotObject').

Comment: I wouldn't do the above, the function is not intended to be used in end user code.  Could you post the VB.net?

Comment: @MikeMiller: Good catch - didn't notice that.

Comment: The vb code  - @MikeMiller :                                                                **Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal A As TopologyEdge, ByVal B As TopologyEdge) As Object
            Return Operators.NotObject(A = B)
End Operator**

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just

```
    public static object operator !=(TopologyEdge A, TopologyEdge B)
    {
        return (A != B);
    }
```

The NotObject is the function called made when you use Not in vb.net.

Comment: From this I got error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0023 Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'object' NMesh C:\Users\Petras\OneDrive\02_VisualStudio\NMesh\NMesh\Geometry\TopologyEdge.cs 164 Active
But this works fine return Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.NotObject(A == B);

Comment: Updated the answer.